# why i cannot add migration in .NET Core CLI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, maui, blazor-hybrid

```
PM> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
Build started...
Build succeeded.
dotnet : The specified deps.json [C:\Users\Alif Firdaus\OneDrive\Documents\Project Jutanam\SurauApp\bin\Debug\net8.0-android\SurauApp.deps.json] does not exist
At line:1 char:1
    + dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The specified d... does not exist:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

[image]

I attempted to add a migration using the `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` command, but I encountered an error message stating that the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support Android platforms.

Comment: Migrations have nothing to do with Blazor or any kind of UI. Which EF Core version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing mix and match

Basically you are using dotnet cli command in visual studio if you want to use that then same do with dotnet cli

otherwise if you want to use visual studio then use the visual studio command like following

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

In visual studio. For more reference see this link they have clearly mentioned both command

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs